# v-model throws ReferenceError only in Production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I have the following View in Vue:

```
<script setup>
import Overwrite from "../components/Overwrite.vue";
</script>
<template>
  <div>

      ...

      <textarea v-model="text" cols="99" rows="20"></textarea>

      ... 

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: ""
    };
  },
  components: { Overwrite: Overwrite },
};
</script>
```

Everything works perfectly fine when I start the application with `npm run dev`.

However, when I build the app for production and run it, I get the following error as soon as I type anything into the textarea:

```
index.57b77955.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.t.onUpdate:modelValue.s.<computed>.s.<computed> [as _assign] (index.57b77955.js:3:1772)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (vendor.31761432.js:1:53163)
```

I also have other form elements that show the exact same behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your build process? BTW, the <script setup> above is meaningless, import your component in <script> block below will work as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a maximum of 1 × `<script>` tag and a maximum of 1 × `<script setup>` per vue component.

Their outputs will be merged and the object resulting from merging their implicit or explicit exports is available in `<template>`.

But ***they are not connected.*** Which means: do not expect any of the two `script` tags to have visibility over the other one's `import`s.

The worst part is that, although the first `<script setup>` does declare `Ovewrite` when you import it (so it should become usable in `<template>`),  the second one overwrites it when you use `components: { Overwrite: Overwrite }`, because `Overwrite` is not defined in the second script. So your `components` declaration is equivalent to:

```
components: { Overwrite: undefined }
```

, which overwrites the value already declared by `<script setup>`.

---

This gives you two possible solutions:

**Solution A:**

```
<script>
import Overwrite from "../components/Overwrite.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Overwrite
  },
  // you don't need `data` (which is Options API). use `setup` instead
  setup: () => ({
    text: ref('')
  })
}
</script>
```

**Solution B:**

```
<script setup>
import Overwrite from "../components/Overwrite.vue";
const text = ref('')
</script>
```

---

Or even:

```
<script setup>
import Overwrite from "../components/Overwrite.vue";
</script>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ text: "" })
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using only the setup script tag? Using it only for imports this way doesn't make sense. If you import a component in setup script tags you don't need to set `components` maybe the issue is related to that.

Also you could try the full setup way then:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Overwrite from "../components/Overwrite.vue";

const text = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <div>

      ...

      <textarea v-model="text" cols="99" rows="20"></textarea>

      ... 

  </div>
</template>
```